# Issue with two stage in_array checking, wont allow second statement to be processed

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, scope

#### Background:

I am creating a method to pull information from one table, check if it exists in a second table, and if it doesn't then insert the information.  While comparing the data, the check must first see if the name matches, and then proceed to check if the account number matches the corresponding name.  This code is heavily commented so a step by step process can be followed as well.  I am greatly appreciative of all the help the masters of stackexchange bring to the table, so after scratching my head for a while, I bring my issues to the table.

Apparently my code is breaking when it goes to check the account number, even though a matching name exists.  According to my best skills, all the code should work perfectly.

As you will be able to see through the print_f of all_validation_names, as well as all_validation_accounts, the information of the first passing statement is  contained in the array with a check.

My question is as follows:  Why can't a varchar variable, stored in an array with a corresponding key ($check_account_number) be passed into in_array.  The function always returns else, where although the variable is "1", it isn't found using the corresponding key in $all_validation_accounts.

Please help!

#### Code For The Processing Of The Script

```
        if (in_array($check_agency_name,$all_validation_names))
        { 

            //Set a marker for the key index on which row the name was found
            $array_key= array_search($check_agency_name, $all_validation_names);

            //Now check if the account corresponds to the right account name
            if (in_array($check_account_number,$all_validation_accounts["$array_key"]))
            //NOTE: i've even tried strict comparison using third parameter true    
            {
            //Bounce Them If the Account Matches with a name So theres no duplicate entry (works)
            }

            //If the account doesn't correspond to the right account name, enter the information
            else
            //ALSO DOESNT WORK: if (!(in_array($check_account_number,$all_validation_accounts["$array_key"])))
            {
            // The account doesn't exist for the name, so enter the information
            //CODE TO ENTER INFORMATION THEN BOUNCE (works)
            break;  
            }
        }
```

#### The Output:

> Passing Name to match: a And Account:1
>
> There are accounts existing, so heres all the validation arrays:
>   all_validation_names:  Array (
>       [0] => a
>       [1] => a
>       [2] => b
>   )
>
> all validation accounts:  Array
>   (
>       [0] => 1
>       [1] => 2
>       [2] => 2
>   )
>
> the system found check_agency_name in the array all_validation_names,
>   so lets check the account number with this key: 0
>
> the account name existed, but the system didn't find the account
>   number match, so it must enter it as if the account never existed
>
> heres the information that should be entered: used_selector: 0
>   agency_name:A address:  city:  state:  zip:  account_number: 1
>
> now the system should enter the info, and bounce the client out

Comment: Please rephrase your problem in the form of a question. A small, self-contained runnable example wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Rephrased the question line, but unfortunately I am unfamiliar with a way to fiddle mysql output.  Therefore the output of the arrays is outputted to reference the output of the tables.... (In output: first field is the one pulled from the first table, and the print_f statements refer to the information pulled from the second statement)

Comment: I still don't see any sentences ending in a question mark...

Comment: ... Its in the second paragraph lol.... Anyone else having problems finding the question?  Not to be rude at all, but I was unfamiliar that all questions had to be followed by a question mark.  X-D

Comment: Please phrase your exact problem. And try to narrow the code range you think the bug is generated. Code is buggy, at least full of redundance forming a bulk of spagetti. Look down for the answer to see why I say that. Note It is not the answer to the question..

Comment: Recommendation to cut the code taken into consideration...I will work on it now.  Gimme a few minutes, thanks

Comment: And on another note, I love the reoptimization of the trim code on steroids....I'll test it a lil later

Comment: Question has been dramatically changed.  Just call me a SO n00b.

Comment: "a varchar variable, stored in an array with a corresponding key ($check_account_number)" -- I have no idea what this means.

Comment: basically its stored in the table under varchar.... which in theory should also has no relation to how its called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question by rethinking the logic behind the checks.
Thank you for all your responses.

Here is a link to the solution.  I have posted it online to share as well as optimize, because all the great minds of SO deserve it!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775444/entry-of-items-checking-sharing-optimization-from-post-form

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Your code is full of redundancies and is extremely difficult to read. You need to do a lot more work on your own to narrow down the issue before you come to SO for assistance. It's unlikely anyone will have the patience to step through your code, especially since they also can't run it without having a copy of your invisible database.

However, I felt obligated to tell you that your `__trim()` function is poorly named *and* far too complicated for what it does. It is not a "trimmer", since unlike the real `trim()` it removes characters from the "inside" of strings as well as the ends. And your implementation is far too complex.

It is the same as this one-line function:

```
function __trim($str, $charlist=" \t\r\n\0\x0B") {
    return str_replace(str_split($charlist), '', $str);
}
```

Once I saw that forty-line `__trim` function I lost the will to read any more code in the question.

### Update

You've narrowed down your question, good. I'll attempt to infer the state of the program at this point. (This is something you should have done for us....)

Slimming your code to very minimum:

```
if (in_array($check_agency_name, $all_validation_names)) { 
    $array_key = array_search($check_agency_name, $all_validation_names);
    if (in_array($check_account_number, $all_validation_accounts["$array_key"])) {
        error_log('IF-BRANCH');
    } else {
        error_log('ELSE-BRANCH');
        // break;  // Removed because it makes no sense here.
    }
}
```

Let's see what the values of these vars are:

```
$check_agency_name = 'a'
$all_validation_accounts = array(1, 2, 2);
$all_validation_names = array('a', 'a', 'b');
$array_key = "0";
$check_account_number = ???
```

You haven't told us what `$check_account_number` is. However we still know enough to see at least one thing that is wrong. The following lines are all the same (just replacing variable names with values):

```
in_array($check_account_number, $all_validation_accounts["$array_key"])
in_array($check_account_number, $all_validation_accounts["0"])
in_array($check_account_number, $all_validation_accounts[0])
in_array($check_account_number, 1)
```

Here we see that regardless of the value of `$check_account_number`, `in_array()` will return false because its second argument ***is not an array***!

(By the way, don't quote key lookups: `$all_validation_accounts[$array_key]` is more straightforward--the quoting accomplishes nothing except to obscure your intent.)

This code would also produce an error `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in /file/name.php on line ##`. This points you to the problem right away, and you would have seen it if you had checked your error logs. Set your PHP error reporting very high (`E_ALL | E_STRICT`), watch your error logs, and make sure your program does not produce any error output while running normally. If you see anything, fix your code.

Comment: +1 I completely agree with that :D. Oh, btw, the trim either trims with whitespace or an alternate charlist. Which is not obvious because of the coding style ... "Once I saw that forty-line __trim function I lost the will to read any more code in the question"  That is the spirit...:D

Comment: o.O   Now i just feel like im stuck on stupid and parked on dumb.  Damn, someone send me back to school (lol being self-taught, no wonder why so many people do a better job)... Should also explain the deprecated mySQL

Comment: the value of check_account-number is "1".  and maybe i misread the answer, but all_validation_accounts is indeed an array....(from your example above)....  I greatly appreciate your assistance

Comment: and in regards to the error logs, ive been working for days to get error logging turned on, but cant find the option on bluehost to do so for the life of me (even after reconfiguring the php.ini)

Comment: also, I posted another question which you may be able to point me in the right direction with...feel free to take a stab at it through my profile link

Comment: `$all_validation_accounts` is an array, but `$all_validation_accounts[$array_key]` **is not**! Read more carefully.

Comment: I would recommend using a local server on your own computer while learning and developing together. Google "Xampp". It is easy to set up and also you can control php.ini and a lot other parameters. The default php.ini in xampp is for development with all errors and warnings enabled.

Comment: @lhsan I use easy-php as my local testing server, but theres a "issue" with that because my project team also uses the same Mysql tables, so an active hosted solution is used...

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: this is not the answer to the question**

Lets start from your trim on steroids:

Better optimize it with in built php functions as follows:

```
function __trim($str, $charlist = '') {
     $result = '';
     /* list of forbidden chars to be trimmed */
     $forbidden_list = array(" ", "\t", "\r", "\n", "\0", "\x0B");

     if (empty($charlist)) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){ 
             if(!in_array($str[$i],$forbidden_list))$result .= $str[$i];
         }
     } else {           // else means in case if (condition) was not met
         for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
             if(strpos($charlist, $str[$i])===false)$result .= $str[$i]; 
         }
     }
     return ($result);
 }
```

**Ritual Lecture**

Stop using mysql. It is **deprecated**. Using it means inviting trouble.

Comment: I apologize, standard MySQL is the language I am most familiar in.  I must study up on PDO based functions before reoptimizing the codebase currently...But then again, its on a long list of things to do...

Comment: mysqli interface is very close to mysql. It will take seconds to adopt that.

Comment: I have Fixed the issue after rethinking the logic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775444/entry-of-items-checking-sharing-optimization-from-post-form